# Error while connecting UWP with remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I want to connect UWP to SQL Server Database. I used below code to do that.

```
private LogIn GetDetails(string UserName)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connectionString.DataSource = "IP,Port";
    connectionString.InitialCatalog = "Database Name";
    connectionString.UserID = "sa";
    connectionString.Password = "Password";
    var logIn = new LogIn();
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM Login where UserName = '{UserName}'";
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            logIn.UserName = reader.GetString(0);
                            logIn.Password = reader.GetString(1);
                            logIn.Type = reader.GetString(2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return logIn;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code throws below exception

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

So I tried to open the SQL Server database in Server Explorer of Visual Studio. It connection opened properly but If I open the Tables folder It shows

[image]

So I tried to open the SQL Server database in SQL Server Management Studio. In that, It works properly. Connection opened properly and also I can view the tables inside Tables folder.

[image]

Don't have any idea about the place of error. Maybe in Code or Server Explorer of Visual Studio or SQL Server configuration of the server computer.

**Solution tried**

- Creating a new SQL Server Login account and log in through new the
  new account
- Enabled Mixed Mode using below command

  ```
  ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='newpassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
  GO
  ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
  GO
  ```

Comment: Did you enable TCP/IP protocol in the SQL Server configuration manager? Also make sure you declare all the required network related capabilities in your appx manifest.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Yes. I can open the connection in SQLSMS in the client computer. Also, I used WCF to connect to the SQL server before FCU, in that it works perfectly.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT What capabilities should I enable in the manifest?

Comment: @AVK Come on, It's not a duplicate. This is regarding the error not about How to.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Setting `Private Network (Client & Server)` capabilitie solve my problem

Comment: @AVK If you see that post, you can see one of the answers is mine. That post and this post are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the required networking capabilities are declared in your appx manifest. Depending on your networking setup/configuration these are the ones to check for:

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
<uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable *Mixed Mode* and 'sa' user for logon.

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='newpassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
GO
```

Taken from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/35505/cant-connect-to-sql-server-using-sa-account-what-im-missing).

Answer (score 0):

Set below capabilities in `Package.appxmanifest`

- Internet (Client & Server)
- Private Network (Client & Server)